# Syncing Child component to accept props after Parent component gets API Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

Im running into a issue where I can't manage to render my child components because the data retrieved from the API doesn't happen before the child component gets rendered, leaving me getting a error from my child component:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Since the property its relying on from the parent is undefined before API data is fetched.

Below is Featured component (the parent):

```
export default class Featured extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            restaurants :[],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/restaurants')
        .then(results => {
            return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let restaurants = data.items.map((item) => {
                return (
                    {
                        name: item.name,
                        type: item.type,
                        overallRating: item.overallRating,
                        url: item.url
                    }
                )
            })
            this.setState({restaurants: restaurants});
            console.log(this.state.restaurants);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Grid>
               <Row className="show-grid text-center">
                    <Col xs={12} sm={4} className="resto-wrapper">
                    <RestaurantCard restaurant = {this.state.restaurants[0]}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={4} className="resto-wrapper">
                      <RestaurantCard restaurant = {this.state.restaurants[0]}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={4} className="resto-wrapper">
                      <RestaurantCard restaurant = {this.state.restaurants[0]}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row> 
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the RestaurantCard component (the child):

```
export default class RestaurantCard extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="restaurantCard">
                <h1>CARD</h1>
                <h1>{this.props.restaurant.name}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What i've tried:
ComponentWillMount, didn't work. 
Separating the data retrieval to a different method and calling it inside the Will/Did mount lifecycle methods, didn't work.

Now I am stuck because I'm not sure what to do. The state object begins as empty but once the API is done it has the info, how do i time the render to run after the API is done, or in a better fashion?

I was thinking of implementing some sort of buffer or something to indicate api is being loaded but I didn't know how to do that in React, I thought ComponentWill was doing that but it seems not. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do to make sur that you get the result of your api call before returning the value of your props

in your child component `RestaurantCard` added an if statement to check for the value of the props before rendering the values

```
export default class RestaurantCard extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
    if(!this.props.restaurant){
          return(<div>Loading .......</div>
         }
        return (
            <div className="restaurantCard">
                <h1>CARD</h1>
                <h1>{this.props.restaurant.name}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh this is perfect didn't think it was this simple, thank you!